# SQL cursor with OR statement

Tags: sql, cursors

I've taken over a project for someone and at this point we are trying to get the application useable, and not worried about the best way to do it.  That said, there seems to be a problem with a Cursor that I can't figure out. The select statement in my cursor returns 6 rows...

```
DECLARE testCursor cursor for 

select r.fldcode, r.rescode, r.[class], f.[print], r.[r print], f.[requestor], r.[r requestor]
    from field f INNER JOIN resv r 
    ON f.fldcode=r.fldcode
    where f.requestor = 'Admin Resdas' OR r.[r requestor] = 'Admin Resdas'

Open testCursor
Fetch Next from testCursor;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
        PRINT 'IN HERE'
        Fetch Next FROM testCursor
    END

close testCursor
Deallocate testCursor
```

If I run this in SQL Management studio it just keeps running but if I change the 'OR' to 'AND' the cursor runs just fine.  What am I missing that makes it not run correctly with an 'OR' statement?  There will be times that not both columns are populated and this is why I need the 'OR' to work it just doesn't make sense as the statement executes fine by itself.

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Maybe try using where 'Admin Resdas' In (f.requestor , r.[r requestor])

Comment: The `OR` query should return more rows, but it shouldn't cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Query works fine, the result set of your `FOR` query is likely just very large.

Comment: How many records in field and resv contain 'Admin Resdas'? `Select count(*), 'F' as tbl from field where requestor='Admin Resdas' union all select count(*), 'r' as tbl from resv where [r requestor] = 'Admin Resdas'`  you say 6 when and... but or could be 1million...  this select may help quantify the problem

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier, I tried the 'Admin Resdas' In (f.requestor, r.[r requestor]) and had the same issue.

Comment: When I run just the query with the OR statement it returns the same 6 rows as the AND statement.

Comment: I tried the Union statement in the answer below from antlersoft and the cursor runs quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be an index on f.requestor and/or r.requestor that it can use to evaluate the query with the 'and' condition but not with the 'or' condition.  (Not sure how smart SQL Server optimizer is about such things)

You might try taking the union of the two queries run separately-- this should return the same result and sometimes helps when the optimizer is getting confused.

```
select r.fldcode, r.rescode, r.[class], f.[print], r.[r print], f.[requestor], r.[r requestor]
    from field f INNER JOIN resv r 
    ON f.fldcode=r.fldcode
    where f.requestor = 'Admin Resdas'
union
select r.fldcode, r.rescode, r.[class], f.[print], r.[r print], f.[requestor], r.[r requestor]
    from field f INNER JOIN resv r 
    ON f.fldcode=r.fldcode
    where r.[requestor] = 'Admin Resdas'
```

Comment: I tried this union statement and the cursor runs quickly!